# Error:- android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

**this is the DataHolderNew class from where i am using the value of tableDataReceived in the RecycleAdapternew class.**

```
public class DataHolderNew extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView table_value;
      static  int tableDataReceived;

    public DataHolderNew(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        table_value = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.table_values);


        Context context = itemView.getContext();
        Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
        tableDataReceived = intent.getIntExtra("transfer", 1);

    }

}
```

**this is the RecycleAdapternew class in which i get an error in the line mentioned below**

```
public class RecyclerAdapterNew extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataHolderNew>  {
    @Override
    public DataHolderNew onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_values, parent, false);


        return new DataHolderNew(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataHolderNew holder, int position) {

        holder.table_value.setText((position + 1) * DataHolderNew.tableDataReceived); //error in this line

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 holder.table_value.setText((position + 1) * DataHolderNew.tableDataReceived); //error in this line
```

You are trying to set Integer to TextView (holder.table_value).
Try this .

```
 holder.table_value.setText(((position + 1) * DataHolderNew.tableDataReceived)+""); //make it a string and set it
```

Hope this resolves your issue.